# Was there any connection between these two characters?

Tags: brand-new-cherry-flavor

*Apologies for the heavy spoiler tags, but this show is fairly new and I feel that virtually all the relevant information for this question was provided only in the form of crucial reveals toward the end of season 1.*

I have just finished watching season 1 of [*Brand New Cherry Flavor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brand_New_Cherry_Flavor). I am confused about the relationship of two

> ghostly

characters:

On the one hand, there is **A**: Lisa's mother who left her when she was little.

> Toward the end of the season, Lisa realizes that the ghost that Boro told her was a vengeful spirit is actually Lisa's mother who tries to protect her.

On the other hand, there is **B**: the

> white jaguar. Boro reveals to Lisa that several centuries ago, Boro (then still in a male body) had made a deal with and cheated the white jaguar, who is since angry at Boro. This incident somehow initiated Boro's switching from body to body later on. According to Boro, the white jaguar was eventually killed and made into a couch that is seen in the ghostly realm accessible from within Lisa's apartment.

---

At the end of the season, I'm totally unclear about the following: Was there any connection between **A** and **B**

> other than both being dead and thus ghosts.

?